# Firebase using phone sign-in without swizzling ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

When trying to integrate Firebase Phone Auth into an iOS Application, I keep getting this error message:

> If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's canHandleNotificaton: method.

But according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth.

It is only necessary to do that if app delegate swizzling is disabled. It also says:

> If you prefer not to use swizzling, you can disable it by adding the flag `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled`to your app's `Info.plist` file and setting it to `NO`.

In my project, I do not have FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled set to NO. So why would this message appear?

Also, according to that Firebase link,

```
Auth.auth().setAPNSToken...
```

is not needed. But no SMS is sent without manually setting this.

Now... when I set it manually as:

```
Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)
```

for my release build, then there will be a 'token mismatch' error. Which forced me to use:

```
Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)
```

This should all be unnecessary because I did not disable app delegate swizzling... but...

So, what is actually going on?